# need links to xml concepts for asp.net 3.5 web app development

Tags: asp.net, xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

We are developing a project using asp.net 3.5 and sql server 2008. I know a bit of xml like creating, loading, adding elements to xml file.

I was not exposed to XML Scema, XSLT and XPath kind of stuff. And now there is LINQ to XML and LINQ to SQL also.

Could anyone please provide me some good links to learn complete XML for using in .net web application development?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C# or VB.NET? Here is a great series of videos by Beth Massi on using LINQ within VB.NET. She covers LINQ to objects; LINQ to XML and XML Literals. Even if the rest of your solution is C#, the XML power of VB 9 in Visual Studio 2008 is a compelling reason to include at least some VB.NET code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx#linq